# How to theme only top level menu?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have the following menus

```
about us
    company
    menu 2
our work
    menu 1
    menu 2
news
contact
jobs
```

I like to insert an extra li between each top level menus (about us, our work, news, contact, jobs) to make them look like "**about us   |   our work   |   news   | contact   |   jobs** "

I looked at template.php and I have themename_menu_link, but I don't know how to compare the variable to check if it is a top level menu or not.

Comment: Why don't you try `css pseudo codes` ?

Comment: @NikhilM // enlighten me please. How do I put | using css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of is as follows:

**template.php**

```
<?php

function YOURTHEME_menu_tree__YOURMENUNAME(&$variables) {
    global $cur_level;
    $cur_level++;
    return '<ul class="menu level-' . $cur_level . '">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

?>
```

**page.tpl.php**

```
<?php print render(menu_tree('YOURMENUNAME')) ?>
```

This will give each level an unique class for it's level. Though, there is one big problem with this approach, and that is that menu_tree is working from the bottom up. So you will end up in the following level classes:

```
ul .level-3
li
li
    ul .level-2
    li 
    li
        ul .level-1
        li
    li
li
```

So, you can never actually be sure about which classname the top level will have, only if you know for sure that there will **always** be an X count of levels.

**Edit**
So, just to be clear about my solution here above, this is the only way I can think of doing this programatically at theme level. If you could use a module like Nice Menu's (like suggested above) you should really be using that, since this is more a kind of workaround than a real solution to Drupal's sturdy menu system...

Comment: This has to be done in li level since li has to have '|'. I don't see how I do that with ul class.

Comment: You could use the $cur_level at [theme_menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) to use the level at **li** level. Something like this: 

    function YOURTHEME_menu_link(&$variables) {
      global $cur_level;
      // Then implement, see the API for default code for this block...

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions only works if the number and structure of the menu links remain the same. The problem is whenever you'd add a link the level number of the top most ul changes. Whenever the top most ul number changes, your css that targets a ul class with that number breaks:

Here is a solution that fixes this problem:

In the first function we output the UL class when the UL is created.

```
    function YOURTHEME_menu_tree__menu_secondary_menu($variables) {
      global $cur_level_menu_secondary_menu;

      $class = ($cur_level_menu_secondary_menu == 1) ? 'secondary-menu' : 'secondary-menu--submenu';
      $output = '<ul class="' . $class . ' ' . 'secondary-menu--' . $cur_level_menu_secondary_menu . '">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
      $cur_level_menu_secondary_menu--;

      return $output;
     }
```

In the second function we save the current depth in a global variable `$cur_level_menu_secondary_menu`.

```
  function YOURTHEME_menu_link__menu_secondary_menu(array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];

     global $cur_level_menu_secondary_menu;
     $cur_level_menu_secondary_menu = $element['#original_link']['depth'];

     $sub_menu = $element['#below'] ? drupal_render($element['#below']) : '';
     $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

     return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . '</li>';
   }
```

Thus the top most UL will always have the number 1.

```
   <ul class="secondary-menu secondary-menu--1">
    <li>Menu Link</li>
      <ul class="secondary-menu--submenu secondary-menu--2">
        <li>Menu Link</li>
        <li>Menu Link</li>
          <ul class = "secondary-menu-submenu secondary-menu--3">
            <li>Menu Link</li>
          </ul>
        <li>Menu Link</li>
      </ul>
    <li>Menu Link</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then doing it with jquery you should try with modules, there are already lots of modules for this requirement, try with "Nice Menu".

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there's a 'depth' key for each links.

```
function yourthemename_menu_link(array $vars)
{
    $depth = $vars['element']['#original_link']['depth'];
}
```

you can check depth to see if it is the first level.