# Theme output of submenu

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I have a menu that should look like this:

```
<ul class="subpagemenu">
<li><a href="xx">xx</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see, that the first ul has a class and the submenu ul doesn't have.

I am using this code to add class to the ul.

```
function mytheme_menu_tree__menu_mymenu($variables) {
    return '<ul class="subpagemenu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

But it adds that class to the all submenus.

```
<ul class="subpagemenu">
<li><a href="xx">xx</a>
  <ul class="subpagemenu">
  <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to theme the sub menu? Thank you.

Comment: Menus are built recursively; it's theoretically possible to override that, but why exactly do you need to? The only thing I can think of is that you need to target the submenu with CSS, but of course you could just do that with `ul ul`

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's a task and the code output has to be in exactly this way..

Comment: You mean like a school assignment? That's a very strange rule to set, there's no value in teaching you not to use CSS. If this is a real world project, I'd advise telling whoever's insisting on that markup that it's a futile exercise. But hey, I guess if they want to pay for the time, you could make this a pretty good earner! Solving with CSS will take you about 10 seconds; working out how to override all the necessary theme functions, and rewriting the menu functions to not render recursively, would probably take an hour or two on my estimation

Comment: It's a real world project... I know, I don't like it either, but it's really complicated and it should be done this way.

Comment: I feel your pain, I have some clients who think they know best too - it can get a bit soul-destroying! Just a hint, you won't be able to use the menu_tree functions to solve your issue, as the recursion is hard coded. The easiest thing to do is build a theme function from scratch

Comment: In the insanity realm, you *might* be able to use  `yourtheme_preprocess_menu_tree()` to set or increment a `$variables['depth']` variable that you could then look at inside `yourtheme_menu_tree__menu_mymenu()` and only add the class to the first menu tree it processes, eg if $depth == 0 or something.  I say *might* because I am not sure if the preprocess hook will be called for each invocation of the menu tree theme hook, but it might be worth a quick shot.

Comment: Hm, I have no idea how should I get the depth...

Comment: @user2171413 A custom variable created within `theme_menu_link()` can help you achieve your goal. Have a look at my answer here: [Assigning custom class to nested menu UL elements](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/78182/16739).

Comment: You could trivially add the required class and depths at a specified level with jQuery. [See line 42 in my theme, Gratis' scripts file](http://drupalcode.org/project/gratis.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/js/scripts.js).  

However, this can also be done with a preprocess function. [See line 428 in template.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/gratis.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/template.php):  

Just a few examples to show what's possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mytheme_menu_tree__menu_mymenu($variables) {
  return '<ul class="subpagemenu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

function mytheme_menu_tree__menu_mymenu_second($variables) {
  return '<ul>' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

function mytheme_menu_link__menu_mymenu($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  $submenu = '';
  if ($element['#below']) {
    // You can set a theme wrapper here or put an empty array() only
    // and theme the second level directly by adding <ul></ul> one line below.
    $element['#below']['#theme_wrappers'] = array('menu_tree__menu_mymenu_second');
    $submenu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $submenu . "</li>\n";
}
```